# While loop in python showing value of next word while reading a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, if-statement, while-loop

I have made a selenium based python program which inserts some data and if a particular set of input is right it returns it value but if the correct value is let suppose 2 then its giving the very next line as its output like 3
i am inserting values in a web form using selenium and if the login details are right it should return me with the login details (its my own Webform )which in this case is username from 1-10 but if the details match for username 2 its again reading the file and showing it was found for username 3 .

```
f = open('a.txt', 'r') 
line=f.readline().strip()
while line :
    line=f.readline().strip()
    print 'inserting username' , line


    if ('Profile Information' in driver.page_source):
        count = 1
        print 'username is ' , line
        break
    if ('An error occurred while processing your request.' in driver.page_source):
          print 'LookS like server time out or webpage has been inserted with a character waiting for 10 sec'
          time.sleep(10)
          driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("Fno").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("Fno").send_keys('18047476')
driver.find_element_by_id("DOB").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("DOB").send_keys(line)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
```

here is the output

```
insering username 1
insering username 2 

username is = 3
```

Comment: I've edited but now I feel you have an indentation problem since the username print is just not reachable the way the code is indented. Can you fix the indentation?

Comment: Where is the line of code that generates the `insering...` lines?

Comment: Just started learning  python 2 days back  , I know c++ so i have a issue with indentation and all , i just don't understand how to use indentation .

Comment: What do you mean you don't understand how to use indentation? What text editor are you using?

Comment: i just use python ide for windows like in c++ we have {} for closing loops and we have ; for ending statement i don't know the equivalent of all this in python i switched to python because i needed to work with selenium

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?